# gzip .js and .css files with appended version numbers

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, gzip

I've added the following code to my **.htaccess** file and the **gzip** is working for all the filenames matched below. The only problem I've run into is any files appended with a version or build number don't become gzipped.

Does anyone know of how I can modify the following code to work with the appended version/build information?

**.htaccess code**

```
<IFModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch "\.(js|css|html|jpg|png|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</IFModule>
```

**Example of Revolution Slider JS version number not gzipped**

```
/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.7.3
```

**Example of Cookie Notice CSS version number not gzipped**

```
/wp-content/plugins/cookie-notice/css/front.min.css?ver=ff52705092b5c9e7ebd0f25314174bde
```

Comment: Your filematch expression ends with "css" or with "js". The URL with the "ver" (version) parameter is for preventing the file from the cache.
Add the application types.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Leverage Browser Caching issue, and to fix this you need to add the following four lines to your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

This will cache any files that have `js?ver=` within it. If you're looking for a full working Leverage Browser Cache, you can use:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

***Improvement on your GZIP code:***

```
## GZIP COMPRESSION ##
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
```

This will cover everything. Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: If I used this method would I need to change the code when updating a css file for example.

Say I update style.css?v=1 or something and i've got the text/css "access plus 1 month" would I need to change that to "1 day" or something to force the expiration and reloading of that file? (Some visitors aren't even aware of cache and never clear them)

Comment: Hi Matt. Yes, that's correct. You can also force cache revalidation through .htaccess once you've made a change without making a change to that. I can add that code to this answer if you'd like me to? But either method should work.

Comment: It seems when applying this the GTMetrix Scan still suggests I apply GZip compression to all of the files mentioning a version or build, does this require server restarting?

Comment: Hi Matt, you need to use both GZIP and Leverage Browser Caching. This leads me to believe that what you're using for GZIP is also not efficient enough. See my edit where I've included a number of things to add to your GZIP, this should then fix the issue.